# SQL-Server: Define columns as mutually exclusive

Tags: sql-server, database-design

joking with a collegue, I came up with an interesting scenario: Is it possible in SQL Server to define a table so that through "standard means" (constraints, etc.) I can ensure that two or more columns are mutually exclusive?

By that I mean: Can I make sure that only one of the columns contains a value?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?  subnormal databases are a PITA to work with, maybe you can do it in a way that doesn't sacrifice the relational goodies.

Comment: Well, there's not an actual problem behind that idea. I just wanted to know if it is technically possible to do that. One idea MIGHT be the requirement that a user may either enter his own name or the company name, but not both. I guess thinking hard I might come up with something better :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can, using a CHECK constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName CHECK (col1 is null or col2 is null)
```

Per your comment, if many columns are exclusive, you could check them like this:

```
case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when col4 is null then 0 else 1 end
= 1
```

This says that one of the four columns must contain a value.  If they can all be NULL, just check for `<= 1`.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see where this is going. However, the check would be much more complex if I have three or more columns, as I'd have to add every possible combination, right?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: It does get a bit more complex with multiple columns, I think you can do it without adding every possible combination, answer edited

Comment: You can also use a trigger if the check is too complex for a check constraint. Just be sure the trigger can handle multiple record inserts and updates.